# Timer interrupts count in `/proc/interrupts` is updated very slowly and is very small

Tags: linux, proc

There is the result of `cat /proc/interrupts|grep timer` on my Ubuntu 11.04 machine:

```
  0:         63          0          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      timer
LOC:         59         44         27         10   Local timer interrupts
```

As one can see timer interrupts count is suspiciously small and is updated very slowly — it takes more than 30 seconds (or even more) for the value to be incremented. 
Though this do not cause any work or performance issues, this oddity is very disturbing so I will very appreciate any help.

---

Here is a uname output, I have Core i5 760 with 4 cores:

```
Linux calculon 2.6.38-11-generic #48-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 29 19:02:55 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1):

The Linux kernel no longer requires a periodic interrupt, having gone [tickless](https://web.archive.org/web/20130504085530/http://kerneltrap.org/node/6750) in 2006 or so. In addition, the kernel has many different sources of interrupts it can use (PIT, APIC, HPET), so not seeing interrupts in one particular place doesn't mean anything.